# How to instantiate an object that depends on self in the init function?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift3, core-bluetooth

I understand that all properties need to be defined before calling `super.init()`. But what if the initialization of a property depends on `self`? In my case I need to initialize an object that has a delegate, which I need to set to `self`. What is the best way to do this?

```
class MyClass : NSObject {
  var centralManager : CBCentralManager
  override init() {
    super.init()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
  }
}
```

This is wrong, because `centralManager` is not initialized before `super.init`. But I can't change the order either, because then I would be using `self` before `super.init`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

Let's say `CBCentralManager` is defined as follow

```
protocol CBCentralManagerDelegate { }

class CBCentralManager {
    init(delegate: CBCentralManagerDelegate, queue: Any?) {
    }
}
```

### The solution

This is how you should define your class

```
class MyClass: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    lazy var centralManager: CBCentralManager = {
        [unowned self] in CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        }()
}
```

### How does it work?

As you can see I am using a `lazy` property to populate the `centralManager` property.

The `lazy` property has an associated closure that is executed the first time the lazy property is read.

Since you can read the lazy property only after the current object has been initialised, everything will work fine.

> **Where's NSObject?**
>
> As you can see I removed the inheritance of `MyClass` from `NSObject`. Unless you have a very good reason to inherit from `NSObject` well... don't do it :)

Comment: `[unowned self] in` is needed to prevent strong reference cycle.

Comment: please tell me what is the wrong in my answer? I just want to know how things should work in the right way... I assume that the answer should works. Thank you

Comment: @AhmadF: First of all I did not downvote your answer. However in my playground your code generates this compiler error:  `error: 'self' used before super.init call`.

Comment: @appzYourLife it's ok for downvote my answer even if you are not the one, however I want to know what is the problem, I've already did this before and it worked fine for me. do you think it's related to Swift version? I am using Swift 2. Thank you for the response

Comment: @AhmadF I didn't downvote either, but as I said in my question, the order doesn't matter. I can't put the `centralManager` line before `super.init`(because you can't access `self` before `super.init`) and I can't put it after `super.init`, because then the property would not be initialized before `super.init`.

Comment: @AhmadF: I tried your code with Swift 3 and Swift 2.2. It gives me the same error `'self' used before super.init call`

Comment: my playground exactly contains:   //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class MyClass : NSObject {
    var centralManager : UILabel
    override init() {
        centralManager = UILabel()
        super.init()
    }
}

let obj = MyClass()
obj.centralManager.text = "hello"

print(obj.centralManager.text)

this works fine

Comment: @AhmadF But that's not what my question was about. You're not using `self` to initialize `centralManager`. I am. That's where the problem comes from.

Comment: @AhmadF: So your playground contains a totally different code from the one you posted in your answer

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. My apologies for the wrong answer.